# Avoid redirect chain in NginX when several conditions/rules in action?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, nginx, chain

Sorry, I'm really stupid in things I have to do, so may be this question is stupid to. 
I moving my site from Apache to NginX. So I must to transfer .htacess redirects to NginX conf. So, I found a good converter and single rules works fine. But as soon as I try to implement several, the shit happens. For example, two steps:
1. nonWWW -> WWW
2. remove index.php from URI

in .htaccess it works fine as **mysite.com/index.php?p=123 -> (301) www.mysite.com/?p=123** , at once, one redirect.

but in NgonX I did the same rules and it works as a chain:

**site.ru/index.php?p=123 -> (301) site.ru/?p=123 -> (301) www.site.ru/?p=123** this is completely incorrect as I assume.

I hope that I just stupid and skip some standard and simple procedure like "putting in brackets" some set of conditions and rules to avoid chain... Please advise me what's wrong? Or my way is only to forget about NginX.

How I did this example:

```
# non-WWW to WWW
if ($http_host !~ "^$"){
set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($http_host !~* "^www."){
set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($http_host ~ "(.+)$"){
set $rule_0 3$rule_0;
set $bref_1 $1;
}
if ($rule_0 = "321"){
rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.$bref_1/$1 permanent;
}

# remove index.php string from URL
if ($uri ~ "^/index.php$"){
set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
rewrite /. / permanent;
}
```

This above doesn't work at all, after nonWWW -> WWW it stops and index.php removal is not working.

```
# non-WWW to WWW
if ($http_host !~ "^$"){
set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($http_host !~* "^www."){
set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($http_host ~ "(.+)$"){
set $rule_0 3$rule_0;
set $bref_1 $1;
}
if ($rule_0 = "321"){
rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.$bref_1/$1 permanent;
}

# remove index.php string from URL
if ($uri ~ "^/index.php$"){
set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
rewrite /. / permanent;
}
```

This works but as a chain...

Comment: I will never make it works... Just learn than NginX in confs doesn't allow multiple conditions NAD VARIABLES!

Answer (score 0):

Redirect non-www to www. Suggested by many sources (inc. [official wiki](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#server-name-if)) way - different servers with redirect in one:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    ....
}
```

Index removal

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    ....
    location / {
        rewrite ^/index\.php$ / permanent;
        ....
    }
}
```